# loading a new form with ajax

Tags: ajax

i have a combo box  what i want is whenever a new option  from combo box is selected new form is loaded below the combo box with out refreshing the page can some one provide the script

Answer (score 0):

Yes download the jQuery and you can simpley do with jQuery/Ajax.

```
<select onChange="$('#formDiv').load(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
  <option value="/pages/form1.html">form1</option>
  <option value="/pages/form2.html">form2</option>
</select>

<div id="formDiv"></div>
```

This is basic structure I gave, You can enhance it to work it in more secure way.

Comment: i m quite new to jquery can you tell me which files i need to download plz

Comment: Good luck. You can do more stuff with jQuery. Follow a jQuery tutorial online. :)